# Could anyone give me some solutions to open Chrome with an automated RPA solution tool?

Tags: javascript, python, user-interface, rpa

I am using a RPA Solution tool people are not familiar with.
But the thing is, I tried to open Chrome through the RPA Solution tool or program but is receiving this message: Chrome is being controlled by automated test software.

cmd shows a message of :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) on port 62023
Only local connections are allowed.
[6036:12108:0821/085345.853:ERROR:install_util.cc(603)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[6036:12108:0821/085345.853:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
[6036:12108:0821/085345.853:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
[6036:12108:0821/085345.853:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords
[6036:12108:0821/085345.994:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
[6036:12108:0821/085345.994:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
[6036:12108:0821/085345.994:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: PasswordManagerAllowShowPasswords

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12172/devtools/browser/31ad3913-bdcd-4095-9113-b8b95f710c1c
[6036:17560:0821/085346.865:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(119)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[6036:12108:0821/085346.865:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1016)] Lost UI shared context.
[1534809826.362][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
```

could any developers give me some solution?

ps. it is not common solution tools such as blueprism.

Comment: *"I am using a RPA Solution tool people are not familiar with"* Assuming the "Solution tool" is Blue Prism (as you have tagged), it's a bit misleading to refer to an industry-leading tool as something that "people are not familiar with".

Comment: RPA is definitely an industry-leading tool and also Blue Prism is. But I am not using Blue Prism but other RPA solution tool. It is hard to find a solution to the RPA Solution tool I am using so I left a comment here.

Comment: oops. I read the question again and it may sound kind of differently than i expected.

Comment: If you're not using the technology or looking for solutions leveraging Blue Prism, please don't use its tag.

Answer (score 0):

[This github bug report](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5966#issuecomment-398200932) might help you. It reads:

[image]

Can you please test it and get back to us with the result(s)?

Comment: Thank you for the kindness. First of all, I tried the step six to create a string, but an error message  "cannot create value:Error writing to the registry." appears.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you solve this problem for me Thomas because I really need to open Chrome through the RPA Solution Tool.

Comment: But then the solution you mentioned above maybe not the right solution because one of my friend who is using the same RPA solution tool doesn't have the"MachineLevelUser..." file, but CAN OPEN THE CHROME through the RPA solution tool.

Answer (score 0):

Generally While doing Web Automation using BluePrism, by default it will gives you the iexplore.exe's path.

You just need to change iexplore.exe's path with googlechrome.exe's path.

And when you execute launch action (as per Blue Prism), the site will get open in google chrome.